# Audited event query for Microsoft potential unwanted application

Tags: microsoft365-defender

1. Is there a defender advance hunting query that can detect audited data of Microsoft potential unwanted application?
2. If there is then how to determine the false positive?

I tried creating advance hunting query myself but they're basics. I'm looking for a query that can display audited log of Potential unwanted application and their filename, deviecname, SHA1, and threatname.